# Repeating a matrix's columns using the padding function in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, concatenation, tile

I have written the following function:

```
A = tf.constant([[1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,2],[4,5,6,6,4,5,6,7,2],[6,7,8,9,4,5,6,7,2]])
B = tf.constant([[19,15],
             [18,14],
             [17,13]])

diff = A.get_shape()[1] - B.get_shape()[1]

Bt = tf.transpose(B)
for idx in range(diff):
    col = tf.gather_nd(Bt, [[idx]])
    Bt = tf.concat(0, [Bt, col])

result = tf.transpose(Bt)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    res = sess.run(result)
    print(res)
```

the idea is that A is a wider matrix than B. I want to widen B by repeated copies of itself (should also work when the row-length of A does not exactly divide the one of B).

If you run the above code, you get:

```
[[19 15 19 15 19 15 19 15 19]
 [18 14 18 14 18 14 18 14 18]
 [17 13 17 13 17 13 17 13 17]]
```

Any idea on how this can be done just by using tensorflow functions?

Comment: you can do `tf.tile(B, [1, tf.floordiv(tf.shape(A)[1],tf.shape(B)[1])` to tile the part that divides evenly. Then use `mod` and `concat` to find left-over bit, and concat that

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov - could you promote to an answer?  Thanks!